# Python_How to check if the value exists in the same column of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, conditional-statements

I'm trying to implement =IF Z1 <> Z2, 1,"" (MS Excel formula) in python.

I have a dataframe that consists of two columns wherein I want to check if the same person is stored with the two different names which has created two unique ids for him(eg : Name[0] = 'Bran D' and Name[21] = 'Brandon D').If two IDs are created for the same person then add a new column 'C' which will have all the results. This is an iteration process. Wanted to check for more than 200 records.

Eg: If their names are not same then '1' if there is a match then put it blank

df[['Unique ID','Name']]

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a sample input? Also, how does your expected output look for that sample input?

Comment: Hi ,Sure! Input looks something like this :